# I'm confused with callback_groups and threads

Tags: ros, ros2, sleep, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to get a value from a topic and after perform some operations on the value retrieved (can't be in the callback function).

I imagine a subscriber and this simple loop (python)

```
while self.__var is None:
    self.get_logger().info("__var has no value yet.")
    # wait
```

On my first attempt, I used `time.sleep` for the "wait", which pause the whole Node, including the subscriber if I don't misunderstand.
Then I used a callback_group to handle the subscription, it didn't work either.
I read that time.sleep should never be used and prefer rate.sleep instead, inside another thread.
So i tried this

```
def retrieve_value(self):
    self.__var = None
    # Spin in a separate thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=rclpy.spin, args=(self, ), daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    self.get_logger().info("thread starts.")

    rate = self.create_rate(1)
    self.__sub_var = self.create_subscription(
        String,
        f'/var_values',
        self.__set_var_value,  # simply self.__var = msg.data
        10,
        callback_group=self.__listener_cb_grp
    )
    while self.__var is None:
        self.get_logger().info("¤¤¤__var has not value yet.")
        rate.sleep()

    # rclpy.shutdown()  # the node crash if uncomment and the node seem to stop when commented
    self.get_logger().info("thread stops.")
    thread.join()
```

Last I used a MultiThreadedExecutor and it still did not work.
Obviously I don't understand the thread management here.

Can someone help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417525/i%27m-confused-with-callback_groups-and-threads/) by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2023-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2023-07-18**:
Can you provide the full program context? How is `retrieve_value` being run?

**Comment by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on 2023-07-19**:
I'll post more code. I suspect I did not understand how ROS2 nodes are supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the additional info posted, I think your second design more-or-less makes sense. You should not use `spin` though because that's intended to move program control to callbacks only, and it only ends when the node shuts down. Instead, you can create the subscription and then in the `while self.__var is None` loop you can call `spin_once` on an executor. This will let callbacks run but return control to you afterwards. I don't think you need a reentrant callback group or a multi-threaded executor in this scenario.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2023-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on 2023-07-19**:
Thank you for the explanations.
I tried to spin_once and it worked.
I'll work with that on my real case.